# Formatear campo de fecha, al momento de cargar fichero de texto a mysql

Tags: mysql

Busco insertar registros masivos desde un fichero de texto, intento tener el id como autoincremental, al momento de ingresar los demás campos, y darle formato a los campos fecha de YY/MM/DD al momento de insertar en la tabla. Ya que el formato de de los campos fecha del fichero es DD/MM/YY.

**Archivo texto contiene;**

44 campos (campos de fecha; formato dia/mes/año)

**Tabla a insertar:**

id_autonumérico, + (al insertar los 44 campos, incluyendo los campos de fecha formateados a año/mes/dia)

```html
load data local infile 'c:\\ventas\\vtascopia.txt' 
into table ventas306 fields terminated by '¶' lines terminated by 'Þ' 

(clave_area,area_vta,fecha_contable,sesion,fecha_apertura,hora_apertura,av_p, 
transaccion,operacion, id_vta,tipo,origen,destino,fecha_salida,hra_salida,
f_boleto,asiento,pasajero,campo19,f_pago,ef,tb,pu,tr,doo,gp,cv,importe,
formato_salto,fecha_venta,hra_venta,corrida,empresa_corrida,t_boleto, 
referencia,autorizacion,voucher,t_servicio,fecha_cierre,razon_social,rfc,
documento,empresa,fin) 

(@fecha_contable, @fecha_apertura, @fecha_salida, @fecha_venta, @fecha_cierre)

SET id = null,
SET fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%Y %M %d"),
SET fecha_apertura = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_apertura, "%Y %M %d"),
SET fecha_salida = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_salida, "%Y %M %d"),
SET fecha_venta = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_venta, "%Y %M %d"),
SET fecha_cierre = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_cierre, "%Y %M %d")
```

Ejecutando el script como esta: marca error en la siguiente linea

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '(@fecha_contable, @fecha_apertura, @fecha_salida, @fecha_venta, @fecha_cierre)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Parece que hay un error de comprensión en tu sentencia, queriendo poner aparte aquellas columnas que serán sometidas a cálculo antes de ser insertadas.

   Es lo que se puede deducir al ver que por ejemplo la segunda columna que aparece en tu sentencia es `fecha_contable` y luego aparece la misma columna, aparte, entre paréntesis `(@fecha_contable, @fecha_apertura, ...`

   En la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) se dice lo siguiente sobre casos parecidos al tuyo:

   > Las variables de usuario en la cláusula `SET` se pueden usar de varias
   >   maneras. El siguiente ejemplo utiliza la primera columna de entrada
   >   directamente para el valor de `t1.column1`, y asigna la segunda
   >   columna de entrada a una variable de usuario que está sujeta a una
   >   operación de división antes de ser utilizada para el valor de
   >   `t1.column2`:
   >
   > ```
   > LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
   >   INTO TABLE t1
   >   (column1, @var1)
   >   SET column2 = @var1/100;
   > ```

   Es decir, las columnas que entran dentro del `SET` **no tienen que ir aparte, sino en el lugar que les correspondería**, indicando con `@`, que ahí iría una columna sometida a algún cálculo u operación.
2. No tienes que repetir `SET` por cada columna, sino solamente al principio, poniendo luego cada columna separada por una coma.
3. Si dices que tus fechas en el fichero tienen este formato `DD/MM/YY`, considera que al usar `STR_TO_DATE`, lo que la función necesita conocer es **cómo están formateados los datos, no cómo quieres que estén**, por lo tanto, el uso debería ser así: `STR_TO_DATE(@columna, "%d/%M/%YY")`.

Teniendo en cuenta lo dicho, tu sentencia debería quedar más o menos así:

```
load data local infile 'c:\\ventas\\vtascopia.txt' 
into table ventas306 
fields terminated by '¶' 
lines terminated by 'Þ' (
    clave_area,
    area_vta,
    @fecha_contable,
    sesion,
    @fecha_apertura,
    hora_apertura,
    av_p, 
    transaccion,
    operacion, 
    id_vta,
    tipo,
    origen,
    destino,
    @fecha_salida,
    hra_salida,
    f_boleto,
    asiento,
    pasajero,
    campo19,
    f_pago,
    ef,
    tb,
    pu,
    tr,
    doo,
    gp,
    cv,
    importe,
    formato_salto,
    @fecha_venta,
    hra_venta,
    corrida,
    empresa_corrida,
    t_boleto, 
    referencia,
    autorizacion,
    voucher,
    t_servicio,
    @fecha_cierre,
    razon_social,
    rfc,
    documento,
    empresa,
    fin) 

SET 
id = null,
fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%d/%M/%YY"),
fecha_apertura = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_apertura, "%d/%M/%YY"),
fecha_salida = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_salida, "%d/%M/%YY"),
fecha_venta = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_venta, "%d/%M/%YY"),
fecha_cierre = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_cierre, "%d/%M/%YY")
```

Comment: A que se debe este error: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SET fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%Y %M %d"),
SET fecha_apertu' en la linea 49

Comment: Había otro error @ArmandoArellano, sólo se pone `SET` al principio, y todos los demás sepados por `,`,  ahora edito.

Comment: listo, si inserta, pero los campos de fecha los inserta como valores = null; Creo que no se les esta dando formato.  A que se deberá ?

Comment: @ArmandoArellano si tus campos fecha están así en el fichero: `31/12/2017`, en `STR_TO_DATE` tú tienes que decir **cómo están los datos, no como los quieres**, por tanto, deberías escribirlo así por ejemplo: **`fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%d/%m/%Y")`**, y lo mismo con los otros.

Comment: listo, eso era, muchas gracias. Una última pregunta, si quiero ignorar 1 o 2 lineas, en que parte del script deben ir?